# Using a custom constructor as a template function

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I have template function `change` that takes a function that takes `int` and returns an object of type `A`. So I thought I can use the constructor of `A`

```
class A {
    int y;
public:
    explicit A(int y) : y(2 * y) {

    }
};

class B {
    A x;
public:
    B(int x) : x(x) {

    }

    template<typename F>
    void change(int y, F func) {
        x = func(y);
    }

};

int main(void) {
    B b(7);
    b.change(88, A());    // << here

    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler says `no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’`

How can I make it works?

Comment: In  `class A` add `A() = default;` in the `public` section.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but will it use the `A(int y)` constructor ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I need without `c++11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a constructor as a parameter like you are attempting.  The C++ standard is very strict on not allowing the memory address of a constructor to be taken.

When you call `change(88, A())`, you are actually constructing a temp `A` object (which the compiler should not allow since `A` does not have a default constructor) and then you are passing that object to the parameter of `change()`.  The compiler is correct to complain, since `A` does not define an `operator()(int)` to satisfy the call to `func(y)` when called in an `A` object.

To make this work, you need to create a separate function that constructs the `A` object, and then pass that function to `change()`, eg:

```
A createA(int y)
{
    return A(y);
}

int main(void) {
    B b(7);
    b.change(88, createA);
    return 0;
}
```